# What is the difference between filled stars and outlined stars in chat?

Tags: support, chat

Sometimes starred messages have a filled in glyph and sometimes an outlined one.  Example screencap from chat showing both types below.

[image: example]

What's the significance of that?

Comment: I see dotted lines between stared messages, but i'm also using a theme

Comment: @wim That's because it's a hyperlink.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Filled stars are "regular" stars. Any user can use these on any message to indicate something they think is good content. Good jokes often get starred, in many rooms.

Empty stars indicate a *pinned* message, which is a message that either a room owner or a moderator has decided to pin to the top of the star list. This is usually used for important announcements that should be kept on the star list so that everyone in the room sees them. Pinned messages automatically expire after a period of time, and lose the pin (though they keep any regular stars they've received).

Comment: What the hell! Is not better to put a pin icon instead of multiple star levels?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Maybe it is done this way, so it can show that it is a pinned post that **also** has that many stars. If it was a pin icon, the number could be obscure. What does  9 means? Is it pinned 9 times? IMHO there should be a star **with** a pin icon or a legend.

Answer (score 7):

The filled star indicates a message that have been stared, and the outlined star indicates a message that have been pinned by a room owner.